# Bazel executed java app engine process won't communicate externally in docker

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, docker, bazel

I am trying to get the https://github.com/nrwl/nx-bazel-example working inside of docker.  I can get the web app and the live reload responding from host requests by port remapping but when i try to publish the port of the app engine server it will not respond to requests from the host.  If i open another bash shell inside of the container and execute a curl request it responds properly.  Is there something in java, the app engine or the Bazel code that would prevent request from being properly handled by the server?  Requests return with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.  So it sounds like there is a default security setting that needs to be changed to allow external requests.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: the address needed to be bound to 0.0.0.0

`ibazel run //backend -- --port=8080 --address=0.0.0.0`